# ggplot labels overlay with breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am using ggplot for plotting some graphs and have some problem in creating breaks(labels tend to get too "dense" and overprint)
here is the code i am using

```
a <- ggplot(length, aes(DistancetoTSS, fill = H3K4me1)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
a + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-600000,-400000,-200000,0,200000,400000,600000),
                       labels=c("-600","-400","-200","0","200","400","600"))
```

[image]

how can i get spaces in between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide where you want your x axis to start and stop. It would make sense to limit the axis to where you have labels. You can do this with the `limits` argument of `scale_x_continuous()`:

```
a + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-600000,-400000,-200000,0,200000,400000,600000),
                       labels=c("-600","-400","-200","0","200","400","600"),
                       limits = c(-600000, 600000))
```

If you want your x axis to cover the range it currently is, then you need to change your labels, or make your plot enormous so that they are spaced further.

Compare:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(500), -100, 100))
ggplot(dat, aes(x)) + geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3, 3))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x)) + geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3, 3), limits = c(-3, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: ...or `coord_cartesian` if you want to retain all the data for _fitting_ the density, but only display a segment of it.

Comment: i do have same kind of data for different analysis,but for that i need to develop a bar with counts on y-axis and with x-axis as 0-500000,500000-1000000,1000000-over etc...what would be the limits for this? @alexwhan

Comment: @abh - I think that's a separate question. Have a look at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ first, you should be able to find the answer there